# How to call AsyncTask method for a regular time interval?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I need to send one command to the server from an android activity at regular intervals of time and then receive the output and display it on the Layout of the activity.

How can I achieve the above task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the sort of thing you're looking for:

```
public void myAsynchronousTask() {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {       
                    try {
                        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask();
                        // The above is the class that performs your task
                        backgroundTask.execute();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 50000); //this runs every 5 seconds. Feel free to change it
}
```

Change it according to your needs.

Comment: Should I call myAsynchronousTask() in onCreate() method? How to start the background thread?

Comment: Ditch the `Timer` and use `Handler#postDelayed(...)`.

Comment: It worked.. Thanks a lot.. And how to pause the above task with a button or any means?

Answer (score -1):

In the above case for each and every time one async task object will be created but in this case objects will not be created multiple times and with out completing first request the send request will be started...

```
private void startFectchingTheData() {

    asynT.execute();
}

Runnable rannable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        asynT.execute();
    }
};

Handler handler = new Handler();

AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> asynT = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Write the fetching logic here
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        int interval = 5000;
        handler.postDelayed(rannable, interval);
    };

};

protected void onDestroy() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(rannable);
};
```